# What exactly does a non-significant interaction effect mean?

Tags: anova, spss, interaction, two-way

In a two-way ANOVA, what exactly does a non-significant interaction mean? e.g. variables A and B both have significant main effects but there is no significant interaction effect.

Does this mean that performance on variable A is not related to performance on variable B?

Comment: Is the confusion over the interpretation of the interaction or of the significance test of a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

It means the joint effect of A and B is not statistically higher than the sum of both effects individually. Your response still depend on variable A and B, but the model including their joint effects are statistically not significant away from a model with only the fixed effects.

This is good for you because your model is simpler than with interactions.

Comment: You should also have a look at the confidence interval!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Why do you think confidence interval is necessary here?

Comment: Well, it it is very wide it might include values that would be important if true. That is nice to know, and maybe tell you that you need more data.